# db2 schema backup

Tags: sql, database, db2, backup

Getting the following error while backing up schema in db2. The schema name is `OFFICE`.

**Error:**

> SQL0206N  "OFFICE" is not valid in the context where it is used.
>   SQLSTATE=42703

The command I used is:

```
db2 CALL ADMIN.BACKUPSCHEMA \('OFFICE','database/config/db2inst1/' \)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

```
db2 "CALL ADMIN.BACKUPSCHEMA ('OFFICE','database/config/db2inst1/')"
db2 CALL ADMIN.BACKUPSCHEMA \(\'OFFICE\',\'database/config/db2inst1/\' \)
```

There is no such a standard routine in DB2.
If you read the [Backup and restore SQL schemas for DB2 Universal Database](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0602rielau/index.html) post where this routine is mentioned, then you must download the `backupschema.zip` file mentioned there, and create these routines manually with the script inside.

Comment: Tried running these commands but all I get is SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "ADMIN.BACKUPSCHEMA" of type "PROCEDURE" 
having compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884

Comment: This means, that you don't have such a routine in your database. There is no such a standard DB2 routine. Ask your DBA on this.

Comment: I'm using DB2 Developer Community Edition on Mac. Am I still affected with that?

Comment: I've never heard that these routines were included into any DB2 version/edition. Is this so hard to create them using the script and check?

Comment: I tried running that script, but when it comes to executing CREATE PROCEDURE backupschema, it says an error: `DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0435N  An invalid application defined SQLSTATE "     " was specified.  LINE 
NUMBER=1011.  SQLSTATE=428B3.` When I look up line 1011, it is just an else part, and I didn't find anything wrong in that. Moreover I havent modified the source script in anyway

Comment: @Sparker0i It's 1011-th row starting from the line containing the `CREATE PROCEDURE backupschema` string. Really strange exception handler declaration: `DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '     '`. Amend it to the `DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION` one...

Comment: thanks. I was able to run the script properly. Now when I try running your answer, it returns `SQL0438N  Application raised error or warning with diagnostic text: "EXPORT raised error".  SQLSTATE=78000` . Is this due to the post written many years back and being incompatible now?

Comment: This is not my script. I'd not hide the original exception as the author does here. Try to comment out the whole `EXIT HANDLER` declaration with the `'EXPORT raised error'` constant to see what `EXPORT` utility really returns.